# MongoDB updateOne returning null for upsertedId

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the `upsertedId` for the updated doucment, but it's returning `null`.

Here's the function for updating a doucment and trying to return `result.upsertedId`:

```
 async function run() {
          try {
            await client.connect()
            const collection = client.db("database").collection("collection")
            const filter = { username: `${username}`}
            const options = { upsert: true };
            const updateDoc = {
              $set: { date: new Date(), topartists: data.body.items, toptracks: toptracks }
            };
            await collection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options)
              .then(result => {
                console.log(`${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)`)
                console.log(result.upsertedId)
              })
            console.log('done1')
          } finally {
            await client.close();
          }
        }
```

and here's the console output of the function:

```
1 document(s) matched the filter, updated 1 document(s)
null
done1
```

I'm just starting with MongoDB, and the end goal here is to get
[_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ajcx.png). It works there is nothing in my database (when it has to make a new document instead of updating one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will not be the case.

Your log clearly says - your query matched 1 document and it updated one document.

If your update results in insert, then response of your update operation will have upsert ids. -  Means, matched count is 0.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I'm getting it a little bit. So what would I have to do in order to get the `_id` of the updated document (after it finds the specific user and updates it)?

Comment: Using update query you cant. You can get it by using findOneAndUpdate